# What's the difference between "on a Saturday" and "on Saturday"?

Tags: articles

What's the difference between "on a Saturday" and "on Saturday"? I've seen "on a Saturday" several times but I don't get what would be the difference if we say "on Saturday".

Comment: You have given no context - a few example sentences would help - as such, there might be a difference, and there might be none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the typical use of an indefinite article, indicating that you're referring to a non-specific item - "on a Saturday" refers to an unspecified Saturday among many, while "on Saturday" refers to a specific one, usually the one just passed or upcoming.

"I want to go on a Saturday" means any Saturday will do, you don't care which Saturday it is.

"I want to go on Saturday" would typically mean you want to go this upcoming Saturday.

"I went on a Saturday" means you went on some non-specific Saturday in the past, or that you're somehow linking that day to the broader class of Saturdays (e.g. "It was busy, since I went on a Saturday").

"I went on Saturday" would typically mean you went last Saturday.

Comment: So we'd obviously need "I was born on a Saturday."